# Get Area of SKShapeNode in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have been trying to figure out how to get the area of an SKShapeNode that has no pattern to it.

Here are the things that I have tried:

1. Make a physics body and use the .area property, but this is an arbitrary value that doesn't have anything to do with the actual area of the shape.
2. Use height times width, but being an irregular shape there is no pattern to it and this only works with rectangles.

Is there any way that I can get the area of an SKShapeNode?

Comment: `lineLength` would give you the perimeter of the shape, or the length of each segment which creates the entire node: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/lineLength. From there you could get the area for each square/rect created by the lines.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Thanks Phoenix! That seems to work. If you want to post that under answers i'll mark this question as answered. Thanks! Bujutsu, its a very large project and I don't even know what to post to show what I'm thinking. Essentially, I just need to know which of two irregular shapes is larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By utilizing `lineLength` ([see Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKShapeNode/lineLength)), you can find the perimeter of the shape, or the length of each segment which creates the entire node.

From there, you could get the area for each square/rect created by the lines.